# How to request permissions on Facebook App without FB.login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've been working on a Facebook app using the Javascript API, and I want to get extended permissions (in particular, the user's likes). I have built the app using the basic login process described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/

The app is only run as a canvas inside of a Facebook page, and it automatically requests (I suppose inside of FB.init?) for basic info and publishing permissions as soon as the page is loaded. It waits until these permissions have been granted before showing anything.

I cannot figure out how to ask for the user's likes with the same initial permissions. I have added the user_likes permissions in the app settings.

I've tried calling

```
FB.login(function, {scope: "user_likes"})
```

immediately after FB.init. Even then it's slightly delayed, and always causes a flickering prompt to appear for a second on each page refresh.

To get rid of the flickering prompt, I can wait until to check user permissions before calling FB.login with an FB.api call, but by then the process has taken too long. It appears pretty late and feels like an afterthought.

Is there any way to bundle the user_likes permission with the initial prompts that appear?

Answer (score 1):

For your Canvas App, you can [Manually build a Login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#login).

In order to request extended permissions, you can [invoke a Login Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth) using a redirect like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&redirect_uri=YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE&scope=user_likes
```

This will prompt user with a Login Dialog asking for the extended permissions that you'll mention in the *scope*.